# How can I create a for loop that filters a master dataframe for a specific state in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a sample dataframe of sales:

| product_category | state | total_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| macbook | New York | 2799 |
| macbook | California | 3200 |
| macbook | Florida | 5400 |
| iphone | California | 700 |
| iphone | Texas | 1500 |

For each state in my data frame, I would like to loop over each state and create a specific data frame:

`state_lst = ['California', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Florida']`

I know the long way would be to write out separate filtering step for each state:
`california_df = df[df['state'] == 'California']`

But am looking for an efficient way to create a separate dataframe for each state:

```
for state in state_lst:
   state_df = df[df['state'] == state]
   state_df.groupby(['product_category'])[['total_revenue']].sum().reset_index()
```

My desired output is to create a specific dataframe for each state and then group that dataframe by sales in each product category.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest storing the DataFrames of each state in a dictionary.

```
state_dfs = {
    state: state_df for state, state_df in 
        df.groupby(['state', 'product_category'], as_index=False)
          [['total_revenue']].sum()
          .groupby('state')
}
```

Then, for example, you can get the DataFrame of 'California' state using

```
>>> state_dfs['California']

        state product_category  total_revenue
0  California           iphone            700
1  California          macbook           3200
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of dataframes containing only a unique state:

```
df_list = [df[df.state == unique_state] for unique_state in df.state.unique()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
df = df.groupby(['state', 'product_category'])[['total_revenue']].sum().reset_index()
[y for x, y in df.groupby('state', as_index=False)]
```